# How to extract lists from Sharepoint which includes the attacthments

Tags: sharepoint

Any idea's on how to extract a list (not Library's) from Sharepoint that includes the attachments.

When i extract to excel the attachments column just says YES or NO but no actual copy or link to the attachment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The property you need to use is `SPListItem.Attachments` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx))

Since you haven't provided any code to work from I've had to make a simple example. I would suggest posting the code you're working on in future, you will receive much better replies.

```
using (var objSite = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"))
{
    using (var web = objSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        var objlist = web.Lists["Testing List"];

        var objItem = objlist.GetItemById(1);
        var attachments = objItem.Attachments;
    }
}
```